# Change background of google slides shape to red

Tags: google-slides-api, google-slides

I am trying to find the answer in Google Slides API references for how to set the background color of a shape I have in my Google Slide. I have given it the title (using Alt Text feature) "rectangle1", so my intention is to write the code along the lines of "if shape's property "title" == "rectangle1", then set background color to red."

I can't see a single reference to "SetBackgroundFill" or SetBackgroundColor, or anything of that sort.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

This is another possible answer, using a so-called "container bound script", which is only accessible through the specific Slide's Tools/Script Editor menu (no other way, or else it won't work).

I found that this "container bound script" approach gives me more power over my slide, and it avoids these expensive calls to "batchUpdate", when using "stand alone" scripts as in my other "self-answer".

So, in a way, I recommend it to myself, but, perhaps, to someone else, my other approach would be a better choice.

For one thing, this approach has a much faster response time.

```
var hex_color = '#54BdeF';
function test1() {  
  var selection = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSelection();
  var currentPage = selection.getCurrentPage();
  var selectionType = selection.getSelectionType();
  var shapes = currentPage.getShapes();  
  for (i=0; i < shapes.length; i++) {    
    if (shapes[i].getTitle() == 'rectangle1') {
      shape_fill = shapes[i].getFill();
      shape_fill.setSolidFill(hex_color);
    }
  }
}
```

Again, as before, I would welcome any comments and suggestions.

Comment: Really helpful. I couldn't figure out how to use `setSolidStyle`. Your answer saved me lots of hours

Comment: @MoizMansur Glad it worked out for you. Sometimes it takes forever to find what seems like should be a simple answer.

Answer (score 0):

To set background color, you need [Element Operations](https://developers.google.com/slides/samples/elements#copy_and_edit_an_element).

> The Slides API allows you to create and edit a variety of page
>   elements, including text boxes, images, tables, basic shapes, lines,
>   and embedded videos. The examples on this page show some common page
>   element operations that can be achieved with the API.

Following the steps specified [here](https://developers.google.com/slides/samples/elements#copy_and_edit_an_element) will do the changes in your specified shape or element. Check the example.

Comment: I am reading your "here" link. It says "The request protocol is shown below. The Add Text and Shapes guide shows an example that blah blah....." So, I click on "Add Text and Shapes", and see another tutorial. I try to work with it, so I copy that code into my script. Immediately, there are problems with that code, such as "what is pageId". I replace pageId with my presentationId number. (Maybe that's wrong). But it doesn't work - the script complains about Invalid requests[0].createShape: The page (my presentationId) could not be found. Any help with this?

Comment: See this documentation to get the [`projectID`](https://developers.google.com/slides/samples/reading).

Comment: I must be misunderstanding something. You mention "projectID", but the link has no such thing mentioned. On the other hand, I figured out about "pageId", and I now have the correct variable where I got confused. So, at least I am able to get the example text box inserted into my slide. Now, I am trying to figure out the other things.

Comment: Good to know that it is somehow helps, share your fixes in your post if you have done it. So that others can see as well.

Comment: I just posted my answer.

Comment: And I just posted another possible answer (which seems to fit my needs better than your initial suggestion of "Slides API"). This one uses "SlidesApp API" and uses a so-called "container bound script".

Comment: Actually, I reread my OP and I see that it was I that mentioned "Google Slides API" (not knowing there also exists SlidesApp API).

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is my solution. If someone sees a way to improve it, I am all ears, but so far, it appears to work for me glitch-free.

First, I find the shape I am after using the following logic:

```
function ChangeColorMain()
{
  ChangeShapeBackgroundColor('title', 'rectangle1', color_to_repl_r, color_to_repl_g, color_to_repl_b, alpha_value );
}

function ChangeShapeBackgroundColor(shape_property_name, shape_property_value, color_to_set_r, color_to_set_g, color_to_set_b) { 
  Logger.log( 'ChangeShapeBackgroundColor(shape_property_name=%s, shape_property_value=%s, color_to_set_r=%s, color_to_set_g=%s, color_to_set_b=%s) ',  
             shape_property_name, shape_property_value, color_to_set_r, color_to_set_g, color_to_set_b);     
  var presentation = Slides.Presentations.get(presentationId);
  var slides = presentation.slides;
  Logger.log('The presentation contains %s slides:', slides.length);
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < slides[i].pageElements.length; j++ ) { 
      if (shape_property_name == 'title' && shape_property_value == slides[i].pageElements[j].title) {
        Logger.log('Found it');
        //slides[i].pageElements[j].shape.shapeProperties.shapeBackgroundFill.solidFill.color.rgbColor.red = color_to_set_r;
        SubmitRequest(slides[i].pageElements[j].objectId, color_to_set_r, color_to_set_g, color_to_set_b, alpha_value);

      }
    } //end of for that iterates through every element
  }
}
```

So, you'll notice that I start my process by calling the function "ChangeColorMain" which also gets my global variables color_to_repl_r... which are defined in a different file of my google script project, but that's not important.

Once inside the ChangeShapeBackgroundColor(), I iterate through all "PageElements" on my slide (see the relevant for loops) and use if statements to check if I got to the shape I am looking for. Finally, once I have located it, I call the all important function SubmitRequest(), which is "expensive". You can't make too many calls in one day, or else Google blocks this function until the day ends. But not a problem if you are making less than 500 calls per day (this number might be wrong/might change).

Here are the details of "SubmitRequest()" which I was able to create by finally figuring out how to make sense of this reference page:
https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#UpdateShapePropertiesRequest

```
function SubmitRequest(shape_id, r, g, b, a) {
  var rgb_color = {
    red: r,
    green: g, 
    blue: b
  };

  var opaque_color = {
    rgbColor: rgb_color
  };

  var solid_fill = {
    color: opaque_color,
    alpha: a
  };

  var background_fill = {
    solidFill: solid_fill
  };
  var shape_properties = {
   shapeBackgroundFill: background_fill
  };
  var update_request = {
    objectId: shape_id,
    shapeProperties: shape_properties,
    fields: "shapeBackgroundFill.solidFill.color"
  };
  var requests = [{
    updateShapeProperties: update_request
  }];

   // Execute the request.
  var batch_update_return = Slides.Presentations.batchUpdate({
    requests: requests
  }, presentationId);
  Logger.log(
    'This is what you get from Google after submitting batchUpdate request:\n%s', batch_update_return); 

}
```

Comment: But I ran into a problem with using this so-called "Stand-alone" script approach towards which the initial responder pointed me. I wanted to be able to set selections in my Slides also, and it was not possible using my "stand alone" "non-bound" script. Instead, I needed to switch over to a so-called "bound script" that uses different classes and methods. Specifically, SlidesApp. vs Slides. classes.