# Create A Color Filled Shape in the Create Request

Tags: google-slides-api, google-slides

How do I create an Red Rectangle with the Google Slides API? The following code is not working:

```
  var requests = [{
    createShape: {
      objectId: elementId,
      shapeType: 'RECTANGLE',
      shapeProperties: {
        shapeBackgroundFill: {
          solidFill: {
            color: {
              "themeColor": "Red"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      elementProperties: {
        pageObjectId: 'gc448bf14e8_0_0',
        size: {
          height: pt150,
          width: pt150
        },
        transform: {
          scaleX: 1,
          scaleY: 1,
          translateX: 150,
          translateY: 100,
          unit: 'PT'
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

> GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to slides.presentations.batchUpdate failed with error: Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "shapeProperties" at 'requests[0].create_shape': Cannot find field.

This resource wants to Change the shape, I want to put it into original request object.
[Change background of google slides shape to red](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48435838/change-background-of-google-slides-shape-to-red)

Looking at this Google Resource: https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages/shapes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the API for `createshaperequest` does not have shapeProperties. Only `updateShapeProperties` has it.

I made two requests,

```
var requests2 = [{
  updateShapeProperties: {
    objectId: elementId,
    fields: "shapeBackgroundFill.solidFill.color",
    shapeProperties: {
      shapeBackgroundFill: {
        solidFill: {
          color: {
            rgbColor: 
            {
               red: 0.6,
               green: 0.0,
               blue: 0.0
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
   }
 }];
```

https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#createshaperequest

https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#UpdateShapePropertiesRequest

Comment: Is this a solution or an update to the question?

Comment: well, I guess it became my solution, after reading through the specs

Comment: @MarkAllen4512 can we use hexcolor instead of rgbcolor?